# In R, Splitting text column by fullstop and mapping to the same I'd by rows

Tags: r, text, split, aggregate

I have dataframe 2 columns with ID and Text. Text has to be split by fullstop and mapped with to same ID.

Ex

```
|ID. |Text  |
|112 |india is highly populated. Delhi is capital of india 
|113  |Tiger is wild animal.lt lives in forest
| 114 | sky is high
```

answer should be

```
|ID  | Text |
| 112| india is highly populated|
|112 |Delhi is capital of India |
|113 | Tiger is wild animal |
|113 |  It lives in forest |
| 114| sky is high
```

Can you please let me know how to get in R. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df1, 'Text', sep="\\.\\s*")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#     ID Text                     
#  <dbl> <chr>                    
#1   112 india is highly populated
#2   112 Delhi is capital of india
#3   113 Tiger is wild animal     
#4   113 lt livess in forest
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(112, 113), Text = c("india is highly populated. Delhi is capital of india", 
"Tiger is wild animal.lt livess in forest")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```